# Symfony, set a lock in a command to lock another command

Tags: php, symfony, locking, symfony-4.4

On Symfony 4.4, I am trying to establish a lock in a command and keep it alive until explicitly released. Reading [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/lock.html#automatically-releasing-the-lock) I understand that this should be obtained with the `$autoRelease` param of `Symfony\Component\Lock\LockFactory::createLock()`, but it seems that even if I set `$autoRelease = false` the lock is automatically released when the script ends.

### `LockCommand`

```php
<?php
namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Lock\LockFactory;


class LockCommand extends Command
{
    const LOCK_NAME = "my_lock";

    protected static $defaultName = 'app:lock';

    private $lockFactory;

    public function __construct(LockFactory $lockFactory)
    {
        $this->lockFactory = $lockFactory;
        parent::__construct();
    }    

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setDescription("Enables/disables the lock.")
            ->addOption(
                'release',
                'r',
                InputOption::VALUE_NONE,
                'Releases the lock'
            )
        ;
    }    

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $lock = $this->lockFactory->createLock(self::LOCK_NAME, 300.0, false);

        $release = $input->getOption('release');
        
        if ($release) {
            $lock->release();
        } else {
            $lock->acquire();
        }

        //sleep(300);

        return 0;
    }    
}
```

### `LockVerifyCommand`

```php
<?php
namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Lock\LockFactory;

class LockVerifyCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:lock-verify';

    private $lockFactory;

    public function __construct(LockFactory $lockFactory)
    {
        $this->lockFactory = $lockFactory;
        parent::__construct();
    }    

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $lock = $this->lockFactory->createLock(LockCommand::LOCK_NAME, 300.0, false);
        $status = $lock->acquire() ? "no" : "yes";
        $output->writeln("Locked? $status");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I would expect to be able to

1. enable the lock `php bin/console app:lock`
2. `php bin/console app:lock-verify` should say `Locked? yes`
3. until I release the lock `php bin/console app:lock --release`

this happens only while the `app:lock` command is running.

Comment: Please share with us the value of `LOCK_DSN` ENV variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing here is the actual implementation of `LockStore`. Depending on which one you choose can mean a whole lot of difference.

For example, if I am not mistaken, the LockStore is `SemaphoreStore` by default. You can look up the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/lock/blob/6.1/Store/SemaphoreStore.php), but the main thing to notice is that it uses PHP's [`ext-semaphore`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php) extension (that is, `sem_*` functions). Looking into the PHP's doc page for [`sem_acquire`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sem-acquire.php), it says:

> After processing a request, any semaphores acquired by the process but not explicitly released will be released automatically and a warning will be generated.

In other words, the lock is not persisted after the main process ends.

The same goes for `FileStore`, though it is entirely up to OS to release the lock, which can get messy.

What you need is some persistent store, like `PdoStore`, `DoctrineDbalStore`, `RedisStore`, or something else.

Just beware that some stores auto-expire locks. You can read more about that in the official docs page: [Expiring Locks](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html#expiring-stores)

Comment: I think you're right, I was using [`FlockStore`](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/lock.html#flockstore) _the lock is automatically released when the lock object goes out of scope and is freed by the garbage collector (for example when the PHP process ends)_